# How to fix "Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\..\Controller::edit(), 0 passed and exactly 1 expected" error in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

I want to show Edit page and update a record whenever user clicks on EDIT button on the records table on index page.

It's basically about the EDIT function in a typical CRUD operation in Laravel 5.8

I have tried several questions and answers suggested by stackoverflow before finally deciding to ask this question because no of the answers worked for me.

Edit function in controller

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $grantapplications = grantapplications::findOrfail($id);

    return view('member.grant_apply.edit', compact('grantapplications'));
}
```

Member Dashboard Routes

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'Member'], function()
{
    Route::get('/grant_apply/edit', 'GrantApplicationsController@edit')
        ->name('member.grant_apply.edit');
    Route::post('/grant_apply/edit/{id}', 'GrantApplicationsController@update')
        ->name('member.grant_apply.update');
});
```

Edit.blade

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('member.grant_apply.edit', $grantapplications->id) }}">
    @method('PATCH')
        @csrf
```

Submit Button on Edit.blade

```
<input class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block"
       type="submit" 
       value="Update!">
```

Just in case you might want to see my update() function

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $request->validate([
        'project_category' => 'required',
        'project_title' => 'required',
        'project_desc' => 'required',
        'project_location' => 'required',
        'grant_goal' => 'required',
        'start_date' => 'required',
        'end_date' => 'required'
    ]);

    $grantapplications = grantapplications::find($id);
    $project_category->project_category = $request->get('project_category');
    $project_title->project_title =  $request->get('project_title');
    $project_desc->project_desc = $request->get('project_desc');
    $project_location->project_location  = $request->get('project_location');
    $grant_goal->grant_goal = $request->get('grant_goal');
    $start_date->start_date = $request->get('start_date');
    $end_date->end_date = $request->get('end_date');

    $grantapplications->save();

    return redirect('/member/grant_apply/index')
        ->with('success', 'Application is successfully updated!');
}
```

Meanwhile, the grantapplications id actually actually exists in the DB.

I expect to be able to edit and update a record successfully without throwing such error.

Looking forward with thanks

Comment: From a fist look your form action should point to `member.grant_apply.update` in order to pas the id

Comment: `Route::get('/grant_apply/edit/{id}', 'GrantApplicationsController@edit')
        ->name('member.grant_apply.edit');`

You have to pass the id in the route if you want it to be read

Comment: @ka_lin I have tried it before posting this question and yet doesn't work. That error is specifically referencing the edit() in the controller and i just can't figure what's wrong with the function.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve it by rewriting my route. Thanks all

```
Route::get('/grant_apply/edit/{id}', 'GrantApplicationsController@edit')- 
>name('member.grant_apply.edit');
Route::post('/grant_apply/edit/{id}', 'GrantApplicationsController@update')- 
>name('member.grant_apply.update');
```